# Get MAC address from a dead phone

Tags: iphone, mac-address

I have a 4 years old iPhone 3GS that suddenly stopped working 1 and a alf years ago. It was already out of warranty so I preferred getting a new phone instead of reapiring it. But now I need to get its MAC address, however both on iCloud and using the backup I did on my pc some time ago, but I couldn't find any way to recover it? Is it written phisically on the board and opening the phone could be useful? I still have the serial number if that could help.

Comment: A MAC address is a physical hardware identifier, and very likely only accessible via software.

Comment: What do you hope to do with the MAC address? Maybe there's another way we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone original packaging should have the Wi-Fi MAC address in addition to the serial number and IMEI printed on it.  An Apple service desk or service technician might be able to look that up for you, but older devices might be out of the recent database or release of that detail might be considered out of scope.

iOS itself as well as the iTunes back up syncs never need the MAC address, so you would be better looking at Internet logs and router logs and basestation logs since they would record that type of information as a routine auditing function.

Lastly, diagnostic logs from the device might have that information so if you opted into sharing diagnostics with either a third-party developer or Apple, they might have records of your mac address in their databases of crash reports and support incidents.

Opening the device would only make sense if you could get it to power up and join the network-I would be surprised if the address or visible to inspection internally

Comment: I've looked on my box but there is only IMEI, S/N, UPC, PART number and a couple of others but nothing like a 12 digits exadecimal number, not even on bar codes. I've already went where I bought it but they couldn't even recognize the serial even though I was sure I bought it there. I've also changed my router so I have to get the old one to try and retrieve logs, and opening hasn't been useful

Comment: Bummer. I was hoping the packaging could save you.